# How I can get the AWS RDS writer instance in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform aws_rds_cluster and aws_rds_cluster_instances modules to provision the AWS RDS cluster (mysql). This creates the cluster with one writer and two read replicas. In the output.tf, I need to get the endpoint of the RDS writer instance.

```
output "rds_writer_instance_endpoint {
  value = aws_rds_cluster.instances.*.endpoint
}
```

I got all the endpoints for the three instances "aws_rds_cluster.instances.*.endpoint". How to retrieve only the writer endpoint?

Comment: What is the definition of `aws_rds_cluster.instances.`? ALso what's wrong with your current code? Any errors?

Comment: Hi Mark, aws_rds_cluster.instances.*. endpoint has all the endpoints. Need to find the writer instance. Thanks for looking at it. Chris answered and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your instance objects will be returning with an attribute of `writer`. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster_instance#attributes-reference

> writer – Boolean indicating if this instance is writable. False indicates this instance is a read replica.

You can use this attribute to filter your list and return only objects that have this value set to true. Assuming that only one instance can be the writter I then use the `one` function of terraform to set the output as the value of the list.

```
output "rds_writer_instance_endpoint {
  value = one([for instance in aws_rds_cluster.instances: var.endpoint if var.writer]) 
}
```

As an example of this in action, I have created a list of variables that represent like your instances resource and apply the above pattern to it.

```
variable "instances" {
  type    = list(object({
    endpoint = string
    writer   = bool
  }))
  default = [
    {
      endpoint = "http:localhost:8080"
      writer    = false
    },
    {
      endpoint = "http:localhost:8081"
      writer    = true
    },
    {
      endpoint = "http:localhost:8082"
      writer    = false
    }
  ]
}

output "all_out" {
  value = var.instances.*.endpoint
}

output "writer" {
  value = one([for instance in var.instances: instance.endpoint if instance.writer])
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Outputs:

all_out = tolist([
  "http:localhost:8080",
  "http:localhost:8081",
  "http:localhost:8082",
])
writer = "http:localhost:8081"
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your help great example. Tried and it worked

Comment: Your welcome.  if the answer solved your issue please mark it as accepted so the question doesnt keep showing up unanswered